# Typescript, RequireJS, non-NPM, MVC

Tags: typescript, model-view-controller, requirejs

OK, so here's whats happening.
I have a typescript tile that looks like this:

```
import o = require("o.js");
export class MyClass{
    constructor(initData: { ID?: string; Name?: string; IsInactive?: 
     boolean; }) {
    this.ID = initData.ID;
    this.Name = initData.Name;
    this.IsInactive = initData.IsInactive;
    };
...
}
```

MyClass is used from the controller MyController and action Index
but when I try and run it...I get a 404 trying to find o.js in (root)/MyController

Of course the file doesnt exist there.  o.js is in the Scripts folder as it should be.  So I set up a configure file

```
require.js.configure(
paths: {
    "o.js": "/Scripts/o",
});
```

Well, that made ZERO change in the ts file trying to find my o.js file at all.  I've been chasing this for far too long and I'd love a little bit of help.

Comment: Try `require('o')` instead. You are trying to get `o.js.ts` or `o.js.js`

Comment: Nah, that didnt work either. Everything works now but that one js library reference and it tries to look for o.js in the controller/action folder (which doesnt exist) instead of the /Scripts folder where it really resides.....

Comment: I think this is the problem: 'code' /// <reference path="../../scripts/typings/o.js/o.js.d.ts" />

import o = require("o.js");
import EntityBase  from "./EntityBase.js";
'code'   The reference path is to the definition file for my typescript...the o.js file resides in /Scripts/o.js  but no matter what I do, it tries to look for it in the path of the current controller/action.  Killin me.

Comment: Can you share your typing file? On the other hand, you are getting 404, typings has no effect at runtime. It's only JS at runtime.

Comment: RIght?  its wild...because all of the other files seem to be working fine...but my import on o.js (which is also defined in a require.config() ) fails to find the absolute path....and tries the relative path to the URI